# printing only even numbers between two numbers that are called in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber){
  var str = minNumber;
  for (i=minNumber; i<=maxNumber; i++){
      if (minNumber%2 ==0){
        str += ',' + i;

      }
  }
  return str;
}

console.log('evenNumbers(4,13) returns: ' + evenNumbers(4,13));
console.log('evenNumbers(3,10) returns: ' + evenNumbers(3,10));
console.log('evenNumbers(8,21) returns: ' + evenNumbers(8,21));
```

So, what I want the code to do is that in the given numbers in console.log, 
for example, (4,13) it should print all the numbers that are EVEN between 4 and 13. However, instead of giving all the even numbers, the function gives me all the numbers that are between 4,13. How Could I fix the problem?

p.s is there any strcmp in javascript?

Comment: You simply typed the wrong variable name in your `%` comparison.

Comment: For equivalent _strcmp_ function in javascript, you could have a look at http://locutus.io/php/strings/strcmp/

Answer (score 0):

Wrong variable in if statement inside for loop.

```
if (minNumber%2 ==0){
    str += ',' + i;
}
```

Should be

```
if (i%2 ==0){
    str += ',' + i;
}
```

Comment: Oh, also do you happen to know if there is a way you can get rid of the extra "," at the very end? Because the numbers would show 4,6,8,10,12, for (4,13) and the extra comma after 12 is bugging me

Comment: , should be placed in separate if statement instead of direct str you are doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to show the numbers *between* the min and max but *not including* either the min or max. In other words, `evenNumbers(4,8)` should just show `6`. I also presume that both the min and max values will be integers.

I put all the logic in the `for` loop parameters, with the `for` loop body just placing those numbers and a comma into the output string. The final return value removes the last comma.

```js
function evenNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber){
  let str = '';
  for (let i = Math.ceil((minNumber + 0.5) / 2) * 2; i < maxNumber; i += 2) {
    str += `${i},`;
  }
  return str.slice(0,-1);
}

console.log('evenNumbers(4,13) returns: ' + evenNumbers(4,13));
console.log('evenNumbers(3,10) returns: ' + evenNumbers(3,10));
console.log('evenNumbers(8,21) returns: ' + evenNumbers(8,21));
console.log('evenNumbers(-8,5) returns: ' + evenNumbers(-8,5));
console.log('evenNumbers(-7,-2) returns: ' + evenNumbers(-7,-2));
console.log('evenNumbers(5,6) returns: ' + evenNumbers(5,6));
console.log('evenNumbers(10,2) returns: ' + evenNumbers(10,2));
```